# Update Query not updating the data in mysql (wordpress)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am working on freelancing site on Wordpress, fetching data from post type 'projects' and when user select the projects then project bidder will show just have to update the bid form the freelancer (bidders)

```
$query_update=($wpdb->prepare("
update wp_postmeta pm
   join wp_posts p 
    on p.id = pm.post_id 
   join wp_users u 
    on u.id = p.post_author 
   set pm.meta_value = '$bid' 
 where pm.meta_key = 'bid_budget' 
   and p.post_title = '$project' 
   and u.user_login = '$user'
"));

if($query_update > 0){
    echo "Successfully Updated";
}
else{
    echo "Error ! Wrong Query";
    echo 'Project '.$project.'<br>';
    echo 'Bid '.$bid.'<br>';
    echo 'User '.$user;
}
```

The data in the `mysql` backend is not changing. Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: Yeah.. So what's the question?

Comment: question is that the value is not updating in the backend mysql is there is something wrong in the query ?

Comment: `update wp_postmeta pm inner join wp_posts p on p.id = pm.post_id inner join wp_users u on u.id=p.post_author set pm.meta_value = '200' where pm.meta_key = 'bid_budget' and p.post_title='Custom Web' and u.user_login='kawish' `

Comment: this query is updating the result but in the code its not updating

Comment: If the query does change your data in the database, it doesn't automatically change in the frontend. You will have old data in the frontend until you re-query the database. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i have make the form in the forntend it is getting data but not updating the data

Comment: **Error ! Wrong Querry 
Project CRUSHER
Bid 123
User fazalhussian **

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got the solution I am using the wrong query - the right one is as follows:

```
$query_update=$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("update wp_postmeta pm inner join wp_posts p on p.id = pm.post_id inner join wp_users u on u.id=p.post_author set pm.meta_value = '$bid' where pm.meta_key = 'bid_budget' and p.post_title='$project' and u.user_login='$user'"));
```